# Check if Value is in Result (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got the following models:

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comment
  has_and_belongs_to_many :knowledgeprovider
  has_and_belongs_to_many :channel
  has_many :order_movie
```

models/movie.rb

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :channel
  belongs_to :order_movies
```

models/order_movies.rb

```
class OrderMovie < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :movie
end
```

Now I want to check if a user has ordered a movie. What is the esiest way to find out if that is true? Is there a way to return true or false without using a if statement?

Tanks at all

Comment: `User.first.order_movie.blank?` will work. But your association names against Rails conventions. In `User` model, you have `has_many :order_movie`, but you should write `has_many :order_movies`. associations are not making any sense to me :)

Comment: `specific_user == specific_movie.user`

Comment: @ArupRakshit I want to check If a specific user has bought a specific movie. So movie ID and User ID is known ... Your solution returns someting different. 
Yes your right the s is missing have to fix that. thank

Comment: @Felix you can used `User.first.order_movie.exists?` is very fastest way to check. an your association name is not according to rails convention

Comment: okay thanks. but that won't return that what I needed.

Comment: @Felix You can check with `OrderMovie.where(:user_id => user_id, :movie_id => movie_id).exists?`

Comment: Returns: Couldn't find OrderMovie with 'id'={:user_id=>3, :movie_id=>14}

Comment: 1) why do you need to not use if/else? 2) if you use `find_by` instead of `where()` it will return nil instead of throwing an exception eg: `OrderMovie.find_by(:user_id => user_id, :movie_id => movie_id).present?`

Comment: @Felix have you tried my syntax?? and are you sure it return given error??

Comment: I not need to. . But Is smarter :) And I thought rails is so short ^^

Comment: Returns the same error `Couldn't find OrderMovie with 'id'={:user_id=>3, :movie_id=>14}`

Comment: @Felix this error only when you are using `OrderMovie.find(..)` i have use `where` on OrderMovie class

Comment: I restarted the server an now error isn't present. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you can do a `has_many through:` association with `user` and `movie` you can check the number of movies that belong to a user(the user has ordered), or the number of users belong to a movie(users have rented that movie)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_movies
  has_many :movies, through: :order_movies
end
```

models/movie.rb

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_movies
  has_many :user, through: :order_movies
end
```

models/order_movies.rb

```
class OrderMovie < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :movie
end
```

So now if you do

```
user = User.find(<some_id>)
user.movies #will give you all the movies belonging to that user, (the user has rented)

movie = Movie.find(<some_id>)
movie.users #will give you all the users who have rented this particular movie.
```

> Update

You can do that by checking the OrderMovie model.

```
if OrderMovie.where(user_id: xx, movie_id: yy).present?
  #user has rented the particular movie
else
  #user has not rented, as we didn't find a record
end
```

Comment: Yes I know that thanks.

But I want to check If a specific user has rented a specific movie. Movie ID + User ID is known. Do I have a Order_Movie.where() ? ... but that won't return true or false

Comment: Isn't there a way without if/else ... 

Returned this error `Couldn't find OrderMovie with 'id'={:user_id=>3, :movie_id=>14}`

Comment: Tried it this way: `@bought = OrderMovie.where(:user_id => @user.id, :movie_id => @movie.id).present?` Same error ...

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Did you migrate your database with the new structure? What approach you're taking here?

Answer (score 0):

```
specific_user = User.find(user_id)
specific_movie = Movie.find(movie_id)
specific_user == specific_movie.user # return true if user rented that movie.
```